# Como usar Angular JS e Laravel 4 sem conflitar com o blade?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, framework

Gostaria de saber como faço para configurar o Laravel 4 para utilizar o AngularJs sem que ocorra conflito com o Blade, já que as tags de interpolação são as mesmas?

Comment: Relacionado: [Incompatilidade entre Blade e Angular JS no Laravel 5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176548/incompatibilidade-blade-laravel-com-angular-js/176564#176564)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para você não conflitar, você terá que alterar as tags de processamento interno do `BladeCompiler` do Laravel. Ou dependendo do caso, você pode alterar propriamente a do `AngularJS`.

## LARAVEL BLADE

É possível fazer isso usando a classe facade para `BladeCompiler`, chamada de `Blade` (que é uma alias, você pode conferir em `app.php`).

No arquivo `app/start/global.php` da sua aplicação, faça a seguinte inclusão de código

```
Blade::setContentTags('[[', ']]');

Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[[', ']]]');
```

**Observação**: Vale lembrar que o `Blade` tem cache de views compiladas (de acordo com a data de modificação da sua view blade). Então o que já foi compilado antes disso precisa ser reprocessado, para não ficar com os dados antes da alteração das tags de abertura e fechamento do Blade.

No Laravel 5, você pode usar o comando `php artisan view:clear` para limpar as views que foram compiladas na interpolação antiga.

## ANGULAR JS

Caso seja trabalhoso ou você não queira alterar a sintaxe do BladeCompiler, você pode alterar as tags de interpolação do `AngularJS`. Você pode usar o seguinte método:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

## Atualização

É possível no Laravel escapar as tags de interpretação `{{ }}` utilizando o arroba (`@`). Sendo assim, já que o angular interpreta essas chaves no DOM, então você poderia fazer assim:

```
 {{ $codigo_laravel }}

 @{{ codigo.angular }}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
<input type="name" data-id="@{{ user.id }}" />
```